# WSL breaks my internet connection

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, dns, internet-connection, windows-subsystem-for-linux

would really love some advice. This is a super annoying one!

Basically the issue is this.

Turning on, my Windows 10 laptop works OK.

Several minutes later, websites stop loading.

- Antivirus checks are OK.
- Using another wifi network does not work
- incognito/other browsers makes no difference
- Tried `netsh winsock reset`

Restart fixes the issue but I'm restarting 20 times a day!

Thank you if you can help at all!

Please see screenshots:

1. Google chrome - can't load website [This website can't be reached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LD3x.jpg)
2. Wifi is connected [WI-FI connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsIr4.jpg)
3. The windows troubleshooter suggests nothing [Troubleshooter is useless](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDoE7.jpg)
4. Pinging google.com works OK [ping test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMEyF.jpg)

Comment: does this happen only in chrome?

Comment: @Sanu_012 - The browser doesn’t matter, the author indicated that everything works, then it doesn’t work.

Comment: @headscratchhmm- I assume this device doesn’t have a LAN port?

Comment: @Sanu_012 this happens in all browsers

Comment: @Ramhound that's correct, unfortunately

Comment: @headscratchhmm - seems like a driver issue. Did you try updating or reinstalling the wifi drivers?

Comment: Have you tried *netsh winsock reset*?

Comment: @Sanu_012 - A driver issue that randomly happens, seems extremely unlikely, this most definitely isn’t a driver issue especially due to the fact the author is able to ping a domain.

Comment: @Ramhound - yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: @Ramhound yep, I've tried netsh winsock reset. It ran successfully but didn't fix the issue.

Comment: I've checked that I'm using the latest drivers and updates for everything, both via Windows update and via manufacturer software (Dell)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this issue may be due to WSL.

There is a *workaround* but **no fix**. Restarting Lxss Manager on windows makes the internet work again.

Detailed here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1203412/wsl-causing-my-internet-to-not-work